# Use i18N outside of react component to render input elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am having a list of similar input elements that I want to render on the screen. I am maintaining a source object with which I am iterating. All is rendered good, but when I am trying to use `i18N` outside of this , it is throwing error. Can someone tell me a better way to do this?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const obj = {
  "name": { label : t("NAME"), placeholder: t("NAME_PLACEHOLDER") },
  "age": { label : t("AGE"), placeholder: t("AGE_PLACEHOLDER") }
}

export const Test = () => {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    name: 'Test',
    age: '12'
  });
  const { t } = useTranslation('test');
  const { name, age } = config;

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setConfig({
      ...config,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const renderUI = (type: string, value: string) => (
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label htmlFor={type}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <input id={type} name={type} value={value} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );

  return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {
             Object.entries(obj).map([key, val] => renderUI(key, val))
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useTranslation` hook can only be used in a React functional component.

The hook relies on the React context API to access the i18next translation instance and provide translations to the component.

So I would move the `obj` inside the functional component (and after the line   `const { t } = useTranslation('test')` and it should work as intended. As shown below:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export const Test = () => {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    name: 'Test',
    age: '12'
  });
  const { t } = useTranslation('test');
  const obj = {
   "name": { label : t("NAME"), placeholder: t("NAME_PLACEHOLDER") },
   "age": { label : t("AGE"), placeholder: t("AGE_PLACEHOLDER") }
  }
  const { name, age } = config;

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setConfig({
      ...config,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const renderUI = (type: string, value: string) => (
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label htmlFor={type}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <input id={type} name={type} value={value} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );

  return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {
             Object.entries(obj).map([key, val] => renderUI(key, val))
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Otherwise, if you need to perform translations outside of a React component (e.g. in a utility function), you can create a new instance of i18next and use it to perform translations directly as shown below

```
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

// Initialize i18next with the same configuration used in your React app
i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  // ... i18next configuration ...
});

// Function that performs translations using the i18next instance
function translate(key) {
  return i18next.t(key);
}

// Usage example
const message = translate('hello');
```

In the above example, we init a new instance of i18next with the same configuration used in our React app. We then can define a utility function `translate` that performs translations using the i18next instance's `t` method.

We can now perform translations outside of a React component using the same `i18next` instance that your React app uses.

Comment: I guess the first solution is not updated in the snippet

Comment: it is, the first snippet includes your object in the component

Comment: I guess it's not being consumed inside renderUI function?